# Powershell select combobox items trigger using button click not working

Tags: wpf, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am currently stuck on a particular code in PowerShell. What I want to accomplish is when a user selects an item inside the combobox and toggle the button, this will navigate to a webpage or application based on the item the user selected in the combobox.

Here is my sample code. I tried two procedures if statement and switch. I used switch  here.

here is the if statement

```
if ($ComboBox.SelectedItem -eq "vdi"){
    $button2.Add_Click
    $ie = new-object -Com "InternetExplorer.Application"
    $ie.navigate2("website")
}
```

this is switch

```
$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null 

$Form.FindName('autool_cmbx')
    switch($ComboBox.Text) {
        "vdi" {
            $button2 = $Form.FindName('go_au')
            $button2.Add_Click
            $IE= new-object -Com "InternetExplorer.Application"
            $IE.navigate2("website") 
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are `{}` missing in your code to surround your `Add_Click` actions. Are you sure `$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null` is part of the second code and not the first? `ShowDialog()` is generally at the end of the complete code except if you want to make some other actions after the GUI is closed.

Comment: Hi manu 

this my code. 

$button.Add_Click({ 
if ($ComboBox.SelectedItem -eq 'vpsx')
{$IE = new-object -Com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$IE.Visible = $true
$IE.navigate2("website")}
})




sorry $form.showdiaglog is not part .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working using Selecteditem.content which is combobox property!

```
               $button.Add_Click({ 
                 if($ComboBox.SelectedItem.Content -eq "vpsx"){
                   $IE = new-object -Com "InternetExplorer.Application"
                     $IE.Visible = $true

          $IE.navigate2("https://ctxau001mel0006.global.anz.com/Director/?
```

locale=en_US#HOME",0x1000)}
   })

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your Add_Click function what it needs to do.  In your case, it'd probably be something like:

```
$button2.AddClick {
  $IE = New-Object -Com 'InternetExplorer.Application'
  $IE.Navigate2("website")
  $IE.Visible = $true
}
```

If that doesn't work, then more detail would be good. How are you building the GUI? What is happening when you click the button? What doesn't happen? What error messages are coming up?

---

**EDIT:** Here's an example script that does what you're asking for. You should be able to copy and paste it into a script file and run it, and it should work. Let me know how you go.

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

function Button_OnClick() {

  "`$combo.SelectedItem = $($combo.SelectedItem)" | Out-GridView

  if ($combo.SelectedItem -eq 'Google') {
    Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe' -ArgumentList 'http://www.google.com'
  } elseif ($combo.SelectedItem -eq 'Microsoft') {
    $IE = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
    $IE.Navigate2('http://www.microsoft.com')
    $IE.Visible = $true
  }

}

$combo = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$combo.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 5, 5
$combo.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 100, 25
$combo.Items.Add('Google') | Out-Null
$combo.Items.Add('Microsoft') | Out-Null
$combo.SelectedIndex = 0

$button = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 5, 35
$button.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 100, 25
$button.Text = 'Launch in IE'
$button.Add_Click({ Button_OnClick })

$form = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Form

$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.MinimizeBox = $false
$form.Size = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point -ArgumentList 60, 105
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen

$form.Controls.Add($combo)
$form.Controls.Add($button)

$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Hi Darkmoon,
i am building the gui through XML. nothing is happening when the button is clicked.  no error message at all :(

here is my xml code 
               <ComboBox Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="161,233,191,214" Name="autool_cmbx" />

               

<ComboBoxItem Content="Desktop Director"  Name="vdi"  />

Comment: Did you try the code above? What was the result? I asked 4 questions above, you've only answered 1, and you seem to have ignored my suggested code edit, especially the part where you make IE visible.  If you look in the running process on the system, you might see iexplore.exe already running, but not showing anywhere; if so, then you'll need to tell the code to make it visible.

Comment: i tried the code above unfortunately it didn't work. nothing is happening when the button is clicked. no error at all. no iexplorer.exe appears in the task manager at all

Comment: @Veck I think you need to add more context to your question. For instance, you have a `$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null` call *before* the switch statement that seems to be adding the click handler to the button. `ShowDiaglog()` must return before the switch statement is run.

Comment: hi veefu, sorry, this code shouldn't be there $Form.ShowDialog() | out-null.. somehow 
i have noticed my comboBox does not have value assigned for each items. how can i call the items in my combobox when button click is triggered? do you have idea or other way to do this
i tried placing my condition inside the button click e.g

 $btngo.Add_Click({
 if($links.tag -eq "vpsx")
 {$IE = new-object -Com "InternetExplorer.Application"}
 {$IE.Visible = $true}
{$IE.navigate2("https://ctxau001mel0006.global.anz.com/Director/?locale=en_US#HOME",0x1000)}
 })

Comment: Let's try this the other way around.  I've edited my answer to include a sample script (with Windows Forms rather than XML to build the GUI) that shows how to hook into the button click event.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hello Darmoon Thanks a lot for this . this really helps a lot. i am able to make the comboBox and buttons working now! i really appreciate you help guys thank you so much

Comment: No worries.  If it worked for you, would you mind marking this answer correct, so the next person can find the solution?  :-)